# Eclipse & Tomcat 9 - Unable to drag the project

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, tomcat, publish, tomcat9

Good morning everyone,
I imported a project into Eclipse made with Spring Boot that generates a .war file.

From the 'servers' tab in Eclipse, I added my Tomcat 9, but I can't drag the project inside (I see a red prohibition symbol) or add it as a resource from the 'Add and remove' option:
[image]

[image]

I've read some things online, and they talk about changes to the 'Project Facets', but people working on the same project haven't had to do anything similar and have followed the same simple procedure as mine.

Has anyone experienced something similar? How did you solve it?
Thank you very much in advance!

Starting the project from Tomcat inside Eclipse, in order to also leverage debug mode (and avoiding the need for remote debugging).

Comment: Is everyone using the same versions of everything, including the tools?

Comment: Looks like you moved the jar files and lost the references, I would delete the server, and point to the right configs and files

Comment: Thanks for the answers but in the end the problem was that the project was not recognized as a web project after the import (I still haven't understood why).
Playing with Project Facets, it is recognized correctly and can be dragged into the Tomcat instance from within Eclipse.